# Excel - Finding nth day of specific month from any day of the year

Tags: excel

I'm creating a daily scheduling report. Not every position in the report has to be staffed every day, but there's rules determining this (daylight savings mostly) and I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out a good way to do this that will make it anyone-proof for the person that needs to fill out the sheet on any given day.

My issue: Starting the first sunday in november, one position doesn't need to be staffed all the time. This continues until the second sunday in march. I want the box that shows this position to be conditionally formatted based on what today's date is (which is shown in E1 using =Today() )

I got something close to working (though it looks disgusting), and would cite sources, but I just came back to working on this project after a couple months of a different assignment:

```
=IF(MONTH(E1)>10,AND((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,1+7*1)-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,8-1))))<E1,E1<(DATE(YEAR(E1)+1,3,1+14*1)-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(E1)+1,3,8-1))))),AND(DATE(YEAR((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,1+7*1)-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,8-1))))-1),MONTH((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,1+7*1)-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,8-1))))),DAY((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,1+7*1)-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(E1),11,8-1)))))),E1<(DATE(YEAR(E1),3,1+14*1)-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(E1),3,8-1))))))
```

It seems to kick in during the SECOND Sunday in November. I'm particularly flummoxed now. It's been an interesting intersection of "I'm pretty good with computers and layout design" and now all of a sudden diving deeper than I'd ever thought i'd go in excel. Keeping that in mind, I'm starting to feel a little out of my depth already and I'm sure VBA could do this easily but I wouldn't know the first thing about what I'm doing which means if anything ever goes wrong because someone accidentally deleted something I won't be able to fix it.

TL;DR: Trying to hit a moving target of a date based off of a dynamic entry in E1. Based off of E1 find the first sunday in november and the second sunday in March of the following year (or i suppose current year once we roll back around to january)

Comment: That code is a little unruly. Could you clean it up a little bit for readability's sake?

Comment: The explanation seems hanging. I would suggest that aside from textual comments of what you are trying to achieve, it would serve you most and the community for you to put up a visual representation of what you are trying to do. It would be good if you an image that says this is what I am doing right now, but this is my goal here.

Comment: It is trivial to calculate the 1st sunday in November and the 2nd Sunday in March.  But it is not clear from your question when you want to calculate the date for "this year" vs "next year" vs the "previous year".  Please clarify.

Comment: I am unable to get a picture up at the moment, but I appreciate you guys taking a look already. I'll try to clarify a little bit.

The end goal is to conditionally format a few cells based off of whether today's date falls within certain ranges. 

=today() is in E1. The conditional formatting formula (B191 in this case) references e1 in trying to figure out if E1(today) lies w/in certain ranges:
Range 1 - Std time: From first Sun in Nov. to the 2nd Sun in March.
Range 2 - Weekdays in daylight savings- 2nd Sun in march to first Sun in nov
Range 3 - Sat prior to memorial day to labor day

Answer (score 1):

```
=OR(DATE(YEAR(E1),11,15-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(E1),11,1),2))<=E1,DATE(YEAR(E1),3,15-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(E1),3,1),2))>=E1)
```

alternatively you can replace E1 in the formula with TODAY().  This equation will evaluate to True or False